# Convert Past DateTime to {X} {Duration} Ago in APEX?

Tags: apex, soql

Is there any standard way to convert past **Datetime** to **{X} {Duration} ago** (*string*) in Apex ?

For example : If **current DateTime** - **12-Feb 2020 14:30**

if Past DateTime is **12 Feb 2020 15:02** Than it should show **30 Min Ago**

if Past DateTime is **12 Feb 2020 16:35** Than it should show **2 Hour Ago**

if Past DateTime is **11 Feb 2020 14:35** Than it should show **1 Day Ago**

if Past DateTime is **10 Jan 2020 11:35** Than it should show **1 Month Ago**

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You basically want the functionality that they have in the lightning component [`relative-date-time`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-relative-date-time/example). Not sure how to do this in Apex...

Answer (score 1):

@Brian Miller is right, there is no such thing for Apex, you need to implement it yourself.

Here is an example of how you can accomplish your needs (note, I have used 28 days for month and 365 days for year, I haven't converted months to years because it can fail the accuracy of calculations):

```
public without sharing class DateTimeUtil {
    public static String getRelativeDateTime(Datetime givenDate, Datetime toCompareDate) {
        Long diff = Math.abs(toCompareDate.getTime() - givenDate.getTime());

        if (givenDate <= toCompareDate) {
            return getRelativeDateTime(diff) + ' ago';
        } else {
            return 'in ' + getRelativeDateTime(diff);
        }
    }

    public static String getRelativeDateTime(Long diff) {
        diff /= 1000; //turn milliseconds to seconds
        if (diff < 60) {
            return 'a few seconds';
        }

        diff /= 60; // turn seconds to minutes
        if (diff < 60) {
            return String.valueOf(diff) + ' minute' + (diff == 1 ? '' : 's');
        }

        diff /= 60; // turn minutes to hours
        if (diff < 24) {
            return String.valueOf(diff) + ' hour' + (diff == 1 ? '' : 's');
        }

        diff /= 24; // turn hours to days
        if (diff < 28) {
            return String.valueOf(diff) + ' day' + (diff == 1 ? '' : 's');
        }

        if (diff / 28 < 12) {
            return String.valueOf(diff / 28) + ' month' + (diff == 1 ? '' : 's');
        }

        diff /= 365; //  turn days to years
        return String.valueOf(diff / 28) + ' year' + (diff == 1 ? '' : 's');
    }
}
```